# How to update choices option of a field instance, not of the entire field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model field with choices:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=(('a','a'),('b','b'))
```

I know that I can access in forms this specific field and override its `choices` option like that:

```
self.instance._meta.get_field(field_name).choices = (('c','c'),('d','d'))
```

but that will change the `choices` for the entire model, not for an individual instance. What is the correct way to do it for one specific instance only or it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to change the model's field choices on a per-instance basis, but if it's for a form you can override the form's field choices (example written from memory so it might no be 100% accurate):

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
    if some_condition:
        self.fields["myfield"].choices = (...)
```

**Important**: you want to override `self.fields["myfield"]`, **not** `self.myfield` - the latter is a class attribute so changing it would affect all `MyModelForm` instances for the current process, something you won't usually notice when running the dev server but that will cause very erratic behaviour on production.